# MVC - Accept JSON when content-type is custom (not application/json)

Tags: java, json, model-view-controller, content-security-policy

I am trying to implement the Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only Header for my website.
In order to do that, i need a controller that will accept the browsers POST-Request - which will send data about the violation in form of JSON. This request, however, seems to specify the Content-Type as `application/csp-report` instead of `application/json` (side note: Why the hell??).

This apparently causes Spring to refuse the request - it seems like the usage of `@RequestBody` makes spring only accept requests that are of Content-Type `"application/json"`.
Even when i specifically set the value `consumes` of the `@RequestMapping` annotation to `application/csp-report` it still does not accept the request.

I have gone as far as using a filter to wrap the request with `HttpServletRequestWrapper` - which seems to be the common way of modifying the behavior of a request.
I have overwritten all of these methods: `getContentType()`, `getHeader(String)`, `getHeaders(String)` to return "application/json". 
But the request still does not go through.

- What am i missing here?
- Are there any better solutions to this that
  do not require me to do magic with the request?
- I wouldn't even
  mind parsing the JSON manually, can i somehow accept it as plain
  String instead?

Comment: I think that you don't need to wrangle with Spring about which content type you request has - there probably will be a way it looks at the request that you miss. Have you tried to annotate your resource method with @PostMethod([consumes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#consumes--)="application/cp-report") instead?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Yes, as mentioned in the question i have tried that but it seems that Spring ignores this completely. Seems like the expectation arisen from using `@RequestBody` outweights that of specifying a `consumes` value.
If there is a way to force Spring to accept the request even though the content-type is not `application/json` then i would gladly do so.

Comment: Ah, I missed that, sorry. According to documentation on `@RequestBody`, it passes your request to `HttpMessageConverter` that you have defined for your application. If you have that component defined, you will need to configure it in such a way that will make it understand your content type (most likely you will need to register your own). Try to see if [this link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) helps.

Comment: @Mercious Do you use spring security?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov The link sounds very interesting and much like what i need - i will investigate and see if i can solve the issue that way!

Comment: @Grzesiek Nope, the project does not use Spring Security.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Afer reading the article and some further ones i would definitely say that this is the correct solution.
For my case i think it's just too much work to do for such a small use-case. I will simply extract the JSON out of the request and then manually call a jackson parser to map it into my java class.
I would suggest, however, that you compose an answer to this question, explain a little about how HttpMessageConverter works and why the solution is to write a custom one. I will accept it as answer then. Thanks for your input!

Comment: There should be already a Jackson-based HttpMessageConverter in Spring by default, so actually you should be able just to enable it and add your message type into the list of supported ones. I also managed to quickly find nice [abstract superclass](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java) that allows you to build your own jackson-based converter with minimum code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According documentation on `@RequestBody` annotation,

> The body of the request is passed through an [HttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) to resolve the method argument depending on the content type of the request

What that means is Spring Framework defines a specialized API for defining how certain MediaTypes are converted into certain Java types when used as parameters to REST endpoints.

[Here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest) is a pretty good article showcasing these capabilities.

There are a great deal of builtin Spring converters that you may be able to just configure and use if your media format can be mapped to their respective media formats. Specifically for your case, you should look at one of the converters available in [spring.converter.json](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/package-summary.html) package. In simplest case, making it work should be as simple as:

```
HttpMessageConverter converter = new <JsonConverterOfYourChoice>(JsonMapper);

converter.getSupportedMediaTypes().add(new MediaType("application", "csp-report"));
```

And then registering such converter into a spring's configuration as you do.

Other available converter types include:

- StringHttpMessageConverter
- ObjectToStringHttpMessageConverter (if you have already configured Spring's [ConversionService](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-ConversionService-API) to read your desired types from String)
- ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter
- FormHttpMessageConverter
- Various XML-based converters living in [spring.converter.xml](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/package-summary.html) package
- AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter (converter built on top of Form converter and capable of handling XML and JSON as well)
- [Protobuf](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers)HttpMessageConverter
- [Atom/RSS](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/feed/package-summary.html) feed message converters.

Finally, if none of the above does not apply for you, you can make and register your own HttpMessageConverter implementation.

Comment: can you provide a working real example instead pseudocode: `new <JsonConverterOfYourChoice>(JsonMapper);`? what is JsonMapper?

Comment: @van_folmert, working in what sense? Depending on how your methods that accept this media type are set up, what kind of type represents `csp-report` data on your end, what type of library you're using to convert JSON to and from string, the end snippet is wildly different, and it detracts from the main point of my answer to detail all that and give a "complete" working example. For instance, if I'm going to give you an answer where JsonMapper is Gson adapter, and your app uses Jackson or lib-JSONObject, then what?

Answer (score 3):

Building [M. Prokhorov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584701/159441) into a complete snippet, this code worked for me to add `application/csp-report` as a JSON message converter (using Jackson) in Spring Boot:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurer() {
  return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
      super.extendMessageConverters(converters);

      final List<MediaType> cspReportMediaTypes =
          Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application", "csp-report"));

      final HttpMessageConverter<Object> cspReportConverter =
          new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
            @Override
            public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
              return cspReportMediaTypes;
            }
          };

      converters.add(cspReportConverter);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers helper me figuring out what was going on with `@ResponseBody`.

CSP reporting is still relatively new and not quite standardized among browsers:

> The CSP2 spec states that CSP report requests need to use a
>   content-type header of application/csp-report. In my sample, I
>   observed four different content-type headers:
>
> ```
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> application/json
> application/csp-report
> application/json; charset=UTF-8
> ```

[What to Expect When Expecting Content Security Policy Reports](https://www.tollmanz.com/content-security-policy-report-samples/)

So an alternative, to accept any kind of content type, is to read the input stream directly from the `HttpServletRequest` instead of using `@ReponseBody` with a message converter.

For example, in Kotlin:

```
@PostMapping(path = [CSP_REPORT_URL])
fun reportFrontendError(
    request: HttpServletRequest
): ResponseEntity<Void> {
    val body = request.inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

    // ...

    return ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)
}
```